# symfony2 twig render nesting sub directories

Tags: symfony, rendering, twig, template-engine

I seem to be having problems with twig render nesting

To explain further I have the following view layout structure

```
resources
  .. config
  .. public
  .. etc
  .. views
    .. WeekBreakDown
      ..  Export
          .. export.html.twig
          .. other.html.twig
      .. index.html.twig
      .. other.html.twig
```

Now I can render the following without error

```
$this->render('NameBundle:WeekBreakDown:index.html.twig');
```

or

```
$this->render('NameBundle:WeekBreakDown:other.html.twig');
```

What I am having trouble with is rendering the **Export** path.

I have tried

```
$this->render('NameBundle:WeekBreakDown:Export:index.html.twig');
```

and also..

```
$this->render('NameBundle:WeekBreakDown:Export\index.html.twig');
```

I get the `InvalidArgumentException: Unable to find template`

Comment: Is it a typo or do you really want to render the `index.html.twig`in WeekBreakDown:Export:index.html.twig ? Because in your Export folder there's just export and other.html.twig

Comment: The names of the filenames are just for purposes of explaining the question.  Was trying to find out how to link to nesting via the render method.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should work

```
$this->render('NameBundle:WeekBreakDown/Export:index.html.twig');
```

Answer (score 1):

so the structure to follow in render() function is 
VendorAndNameBundle:sub/dirs/path/in/views/folder:templateName.html.twig